# 'X' does not appear to be a git repository (I'm sure the path is correct)

Tags: git, cygwin, msysgit, openssh

I want to be able to work from home by cloning of the git repository that exists on my work desktop to my laptop.  Both systems are running msysgit within a cygwin shell.  Both systems are using cygwin's ssh.

If I ssh to that server, I can see the repository at the path /cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject

```
$ ssh TheDesktop
MyUser@TheDesktop's password: ...I enter the password, see the MOTD, and I'm in...
$ cd /cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject
...See the git repository here.  Even see the current branch in the prompt...
```

But I try to clone and it fails:

```
$ git clone ssh://TheDesktop/cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject
Cloning into TheProject
MyUser@TheDesktop's password: ...I enter the password...
fatal: '/cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've also tried symlinking the repository to my home folder:

```
$ ssh TheDesktop
MyUser@TheDesktop's password: ...I enter the password...
$ ln -s /cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject .
$ exit

$ git clone ssh://TheDesktop/~/TheProject
Cloning into TheProject
MyUser@TheDesktop's password: ...I enter the password...
fatal: '/cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I certainly see this error in a lot of questions here, and they almost always relate to a bad path.  But I'm really certain my path is correct.  I get the feeling it has something to do with the environment being ssh'd into on the desktop, but I really can't figure out what.  What other things could cause this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git clone TheDesktop:cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject TheProject
```

should fix it

If the ssh server is not under cygwin, substitute the windows path:

```
cygpath --mixed /cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject
```

---

It is my experience that cygwin passes the wrong path style to msysgit. Msysgit doesn't understand /cygdrive and therefore messes it up, **except** with a single argument on the commandline, in which case cygwin bash appears to do the conversion magically.

However, no such thing will be true for gitshell over cygwin sshd. I'm assuming you tried something close to

```
git clone TheDesktop:D:/Projects/TheProject TheProject
```

If that didn't work, I'd look at

```
git daemon # wasn't supported on Windows last time I checked
```

or

```
git bundle create repo.bundle --all

# receive it on the remote
scp TheDesktop:repo.bundle
git clone repo.bundle TheProject
```

Comment: with more troubleshooting tips

Comment: I needed to use the D:/Projects/TheProject path instead of a cygwin ssh path.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped (and I can use the knowledge myself soon!)

Answer (score 1):

you need to clone the repository itself, not the associated working tree:

```
$ git clone ssh://TheDesktop/cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject/.git TheProject
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with that git wants to find "cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject" relative to your login folder.

In your first example you login via ssh and then do "cd /cygdrive/...", which is an absolute path, not relative.

Changing your ssh login folder to point to e.g. the Projects-folder might help you out. And also shorten your ssh path :)

Comment: Ok, so I ssh to the desktop and ln -s /cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject into the home directory.  Then "git clone ssh://TheDesktop/~/TheProject".  I still get the same error.  I'll add this to the OP.