# git push origin master: 'D:/Projects/TheProject' is not a git command

Tags: git, cygwin, msysgit

I've got two machines running cygwin ssh with msysgit.  I've cloned a git repository from my desktop to my laptop as described in ['X' does not appear to be a git repository (I'm sure the path is correct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731732/x-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-im-sure-the-path-is-correct).  This leaves me with a .git/config as follows:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = GitServer:D:/Projects/TheProject
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

The clone worked great.  git pull origin works great.  But if I try to "git push origin master" I get the following error:

```
$ git push origin master
MyUser@TheDesktop's password:
git: 'D:/Projects/TheProject' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any ideas about a fix for this?

Comment: Why are you using msysgit from Cygwin? Cygwin has its own git package, which does work with Cygwin paths. Conversely, msysgit should be happier in MSYS.

Comment: I had many issues with cygwin's git-svn, which is what the desktop machine uses to fetch the repo from my company's svn server.  I'm running msysgit inside of cygwin because the overall environment is more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched to using cygwin's version of git, as mentioned in ak2's comment.  It all works now.

But I do remember why I avoided cygwin git in the first place... it often (several times a day) errors when using git svn.  I end up having to kill off all my cygwin processes and running "ash rebaseall" to fix it, or rebooting my machine.  It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive recommends against using the "D:/" syntax and suggests using "/cygdrive/d/" instead.

It looks like cygwin doesn't have `chsh` but you could  set your shell to [git-shell](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html) manually in your [cygwin.bat](http://urbvil.org/blogs/bob/2007/01/29/select-shell-in-cygwin/).

Comment: I have to do that to pass in the arg for msysgit-- which doesn't recognize cygwin paths.

Comment: But it doesn't... Changing it still gives me the same error-- '/cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject' is not a git command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cygwin urls : use /d/Projects/TheProject instead of D:/Projects/TheProject

Comment: That was what was WRONG when I tried to clone the repo.  Changing it still gives me the same error-- '/cygdrive/d/Projects/TheProject' is not a git command.

Comment: It might be just /cyg/d/Projects, try to cd to it first and check.

Comment: can be /cyg/d/ , /cygdrive/d/ or directly /d/

Comment: ssh to /cygdrive/d/Projects works fine, but msysgit doesn't recognize these paths.  See the previous question I linked here.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736862/git-clone-works-remote-push-doesnt-remote-repository-over-copssh) fixed it for me, specifically this:

```
git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"
```

Answer (score 1):

First run this on client: 
    `git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"`

CD into your local repository: 
    `cd mylocalrepo`

Assuming server side path == c:\gitpub\myproj.git, then to pull/push to server
    `git fetch user@remoteserver.com:c:/gitpub/myproj.git master`
    `git push user@remoteserver.com:c:/gitpub/myproj.git master`

Of course you can add a remote shortcut:
    `git remote add myremote user@remoteserver.com:c:/gitpub/myproj.git`

and then:
    `git fetch myremote master`
    `git push myremote master`

For more information on setup of cygwin/ssh server, here's a post I wrote that discusses setting up a shared GIT repository on a Windows Server instance running in the Amazon EC2 cloud:

http://cacheattack.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-git-server-on-amazon-ec2.html