# Git push/pull paths not working to windows origin running msysgit + cygwin sshd

Tags: git, cygwin, msysgit

In trying to resolve the issue I was having for: [managing website on windows using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198397/managing-website-on-windows-using-git), I installed Cygwin openssh and Git for Windows (msysgit) on a Windows 2008 server (let's call this `myserver`).

I have a bare git repo setup at the cygwin path `/var/git/example.git`, which maps to `c:\cygwin\var\git\example.git` on Windows.

I have a user `git` that has permission on the repo's folders.

I am able to login with `git` using key-based authentication to `myserver` from my XP workstation using Putty.  I have the key opened in pageant.

I am able to use cygwin style paths in Putty, so for example `cd /var/git/example.git` gets me to my bare repo.

However, I have a problem when I use Git Bash (MingW32) and attempt to do:

```
git clone ssh://git@myserver/var/git/example.git
```

I get the response:

```
Cloning into example...
fatal: '/var/git/example.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I try:

```
git clone ssh://git@myserver:c:/cygwin/var/git/example.git
```

It works and the repo gets cloned.

```
Cloning into example...
remote: Counting objects: 384, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (288/288), done.
remote: Total 384 (delta 85), reused 359 (delta 73)
Receiving objects: 100% (384/384), 51.72 MiB | 201 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (85/85), done.
```

However, if I then try to push using:

```
cd example
git push
```

It fails:

```
git: '/cygwin/var/git/example.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

So how do I make this work so I can push/pull/clone?  Ideally I would like to be able to use the Cygwin path style, eg. `git clone ssh://git@myserver/var/git/example.git`.

Comment: Did you try other paths, like `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/var/git/example.git`

Comment: yes i tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Is it because you are trying to use a git (msysgit) which isn't part of cygwin? As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5875642/6309 ? Although you might try first http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745562/6309: `git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [git push origin master: 'D:/Projects/TheProject' is not a git command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795013/git-push-origin-master-d-projects-theproject-is-not-a-git-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if this was resolved, but I have finally succeeded in getting this to work and have shared my answer on the other thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10509588

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar problems recently with cygwin git not working corectly. I installed msysgit.
Then for things to work I need to do all my git work from a msysgit shell. From my experience most things work under a dos shell, but pushing does not. I recommend starting over and using the msysgit bash shell to clone a new repo and use that shell for all git commands, then pushing will likely work.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, because I'm running Putty, WinSCP, TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGIT with a shared pageant between them all.

I fixed this issue by changing the GIT_SSH from the Putty\plink.exe one to TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe
eg.

```
set GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe
```